# Closest previous element with certain ID (with prev())?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big div wit a lot of smaller divs within it. Say,

```
    <div id="parent">
 <div id="child1">
 </div>
 <div id="child1">
 </div>
 <div id="child2">
 </div>
 <div id="child1">
 </div>
 <div id="child1">
 </div>
</div>
```

If I'm currently at the last 'child1', how dow I get to the top most child1 with prev()? For me it breaks when it reaches 'child2'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$(this).prevAll('.child1').eq(0);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!! That's exactly what I seem to be looking for! =)

Answer (score 7):

First of all your HTML markup is invalid. There shouldn't be more that one element with the same ID in a document.

Read [Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

**id:**

> This attribute assigns a name to an
>   element. This name must be unique in a
>   document.

**class:**

> This attribute assigns a class name or
>   set of class names to an element. Any
>   number of elements may be assigned the
>   same class name or names. Multiple
>   class names must be separated by white
>   space characters.

You can use the [parent](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent) and [:firstchild](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild) to get the first element inside your current parent element.

You can use something like this if you are currently at any child of element 'parent'

```
$(this).parent().find("div:first-child");
```

Comment: Ok, actually I'm using classes but that was failing so I used IDs. And that's failing too.

Comment: Thanks. Actually by getting to the topmost 'child1' I meant by traversing the all the previous elements of class 'child1' first. Not directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(this).closest('.parent').find('.child1:first')
```

I changed to classes, because you really should only ever have one element of any given ID in a page

Comment: Thanks. That actually solves the problem I described but in div I have there are a LOT of child classes. I'd like to 'skip to the closest previous element of a given class'. Something like $(this).prev('.child1') but I want it to skip the 'child2' class.