# Find closest previous element jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am wanting something similar to this [person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775541/closest-previous-element-with-certain-id-with-prev), except the element I want to match might not be a direct sibling.

If I had this HTML, for example,

```
<h3>
    <span>
        <b>Whaddup?</b>
    </span>
</h3>
<h3>
    <span>
        <b>Hello</b>
    </span>
</h3>
<div>
    <div>
        <img />
    </div>
     <span id="me"></span>
</div>
<h3>
    <span>
        <b>Goodbye</b>
    </span>
</h3>
```

I would want to be able to do something like this:

```
var link = $("#me").closestPreviousElement("h3 span b");
console.log(link.text()); //"Hello"
```

Is there an easy way to do this in jQuery?

**EDIT**: I should have made my specification a little bit clearer. `$("#me")` may or may not have a parent div. The code should not assume that it does. I don't necessarily know anything about the surrounding elements.

Comment: Do you want the "closest" element that comes before the current element in the hierarchy?

Comment: There is no easy way imo. And also, how would you define the distance between 2 nodes that are not siblings?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
var link = $("#me").closest(":has(h3 span b)").find('h3 span b');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/

This uses the [`closest()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the first ancestor that has a nested `h3 span b`, then does a `.find()`.

Of course you could have multiple matches.

---

Otherwise, you're looking at doing a more direct traversal.

```
var link = $("#me").closest("h3 + div").prev().find('span b');
```

*edit: This one works with your updated HTML.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/2/

---

**EDIT:** Updated to deal with updated question.

```
var link = $("#me").closest("h3 + *").prev().find('span b');
```

This makes the targeted element for `.closest()` generic, so that even if there is no parent, it will still work.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/4/

Comment: Sorry, edited again. I should have made it clearer to start out with.

Comment: @Peter: I just updated. I think this covers you. Do you know that the targeted text will be in a `h3 span b`?

Comment: This solution would also find matching nodes that are after it in the document if matching nodes are descendants of a parent. For example,  the span that says Goodbye would also be included in the results.

Answer (score 14):

see http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
var link = $("#me").parent("div").prev("h3").find("b");
alert(link.text());
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/gBwLq/

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but was hunting for the same thing and ended up coming up with another solution which is fairly concise andsimple.  Here's my way of finding the next or previous element, taking into account traversal over elements that aren't of the type we're looking for:

```
var ClosestPrev = $( StartObject ).prevAll( '.selectorClass' ).first();
var ClosestNext = $( StartObject ).nextAll( '.selectorClass' ).first();
```

I'm not 100% sure of the order that the collection from the nextAll/prevAll functions return, but in my test case, it appears that the array is in the direction expected.  Might be helpful if someone could clarify the internals of jquery for that for a strong guarantee of reliability.

Comment: Awesome solution! Can be used alone or combined with the accepted answer for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no "easy" way.  Your best bet would be to do a loop where you first check each previous sibling, then move to the parent node and all of its previous siblings.

You'll need to break the selector into two, 1 to check if the current node could be the top level node in your selector, and 1 to check if it's descendants match.

**Edit:** This might as well be a plugin.  You can use this with any selector in any HTML:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.closestPrior = function(selector) {
        selector = selector.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        var combinator = selector.search(/[ +~>]|$/);
        var parent = selector.substr(0, combinator);
        var children = selector.substr(combinator);
        var el = this;
        var match = $();
        while (el.length && !match.length) {
            el = el.prev();
            if (!el.length) {
                var par = el.parent();
                // Don't use the parent - you've already checked all of the previous 
                // elements in this parent, move to its previous sibling, if any.
                while (par.length && !par.prev().length) {
                    par = par.parent();
                }
                el = par.prev();
                if (!el.length) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (el.is(parent) && el.find(children).length) {
                match = el.find(children).last();
            }
            else if (el.find(selector).length) {
                match = el.find(selector).last();
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Please comment.  This was coded with no regard to the HTML.  The accepted answer will only work if the HTML does not change.  For example, if the target `<h3>` is wrapped in a `<div>`, the accepted answer will fail.  You could plonk mine down on any page for any element and just customize the selector and it would find the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

`var link = $("#me").closest(":has(h3 span b)").find('span b').text();`