# How to get the closest or previous object independent of the structure of the document with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xhtml

Example 1:

```
<ul>
   <li id="o1" class="elem">foo1</li>
   <li id="o2" class="elem">foo2</li>
   <li id="o3" class="elem">foo3</li>
</ul>

**$('#o2').exactly_previous('.elem') ----> returns #o1**
```

Example 2:

```
<ul>
   <li id="o1" class="elem">foo1
      <ul>
         <li id="o11" class="elem"></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="o2" class="elem">foo2</li>
   <li id="o3" class="elem">foo3</li>
</ul>

**$('#o2').exactly_previous('.elem') ----> returns #o11
$('#o11').exactly_previous('.elem') ----> returns #o1**
```

Example 3:

```
<ul>
   <li id="o1" class="elem">fooX</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="o2" class="elem">fooX</li>
</ul>

**$('#o2').exactly_previous('.elem') ----> returns #o1**
```

Example 4:

```
<a id="o1" class="elem">fooX</a>
<ul>
   <li id="o2" class="elem">fooX</li>
</ul>

**$('#o2').exactly_previous('.elem') ----> returns #o1**
```

I hope you understand my question! Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018337/find-closest-previous-element-jquery will help you..

Comment: If you can't explain it with simple logic, likley it can't be coded. In the second last example, you want a child of the element's parent's sibling, in the last you want the parent's sibling itself. In the third last, you go up one parent and down 3 children. How do you encapsulate the logic for that?

Comment: @RobG Haha I would love to know exactly what this would be used for anyways...

Comment: +1 for being quite specific with multiple test cases.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
function exactly_previous($this, selector)
{
    var $all = $(selector);
    return $all.eq($all.index($this)-1);
}
```

Tests:

- http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9aU2H
- http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/9N7aQ
- http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/3VguQ
- http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/VBC87

Converting it to a jQuery plugin is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Triptych good eye, fixed while adding tests but didn't get around to hitting "save"

Comment: @RobG maybe, but I don't _think_ so. My solution works with all the OP's examples.

Comment: I missed the class on the elements. So the OP wants to get the previous element in an array created by a selector. A name like "previousSelected" seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at jQuery [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) API. There might be something you needed.

Also, take a look at [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) API as well, which might help traverse through DOM objects.

Comment: While `closest` is close (ha ha, no pun intended), this wouldn't find nested previous elements - like the OP's example: `$('#o2').exactly_previous('.elem') ----> returns #o11`

Comment: haha, well, wish that the op could be formulated a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('#o2').parent().find('li').slice($('#o2').index() -1,$('#o2').index())
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/25Gsw/)