# Get closest previous element with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic page created by symphony, client side I am trying to get the **closest element before the firing element** with a specific id with wildcard (id^='route_segments_). Unfortunately JQuery is not finding anything.

The script should return the following item.

```
  <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" id="route_segments_1_destCountry" name="route[segments][1][destCountry]" required="required" class="form-control" value="GB">
```

```js
$("input:radio").on('change', function() {
  var date = moment($(this).parent().text(), "HH:mm DD MMM YYYY");

  alert($(this).parent().prevAll("input[id^='route_segments_']").first());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="route_segments_1_details">Details</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea id="route_segments_1_details" name="route[segments][1][details]" required="required" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="route_segments_1_vehicle">Vehicle</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" id="route_segments_1_vehicle" name="route[segments][1][vehicle]" required="required" class="form-control" value="Bus">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="route_segments_1_vehicleKind">Vehicle kind</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" id="route_segments_1_vehicleKind" name="route[segments][1][vehicleKind]" required="required" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="route_segments_1_originCountry">Origin country</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" id="route_segments_1_originCountry" name="route[segments][1][originCountry]" required="required" class="form-control" value="GB">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label required" for="route_segments_1_destCountry">Dest country</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" id="route_segments_1_destCountry" name="route[segments][1][destCountry]" required="required" class="form-control" value="GB">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" style="cursor: pointer" class="showHidden btn btn-default">Change Places</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%">
  <strong>Transit Duration: </strong>0h 21m
  <br>
  <strong>Transfer Duration: </strong>0h 4m
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;height: 250px;border: 1px solid #686868;border-radius: 5px;width:80%;margin: auto;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom: 20px">



  <div style="margin: auto;width: 90%">
to;width: 90%">
                <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-10"><div class="radio"><label class="required"><input type="radio" id="route_flight_0" name="route[flight]" required="required" value="0"> Dubai 00:30 26 Oct 2016 Dublin 14:55 26 Oct 2016
                Duration: 17h 25m  Stops: 3  Price: 393.5 EUR</label></div></div></div>
                </div>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <div style="margin: auto;width: 90%">
                <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-10"><div class="radio"><label class="required"><input type="radio" id="route_flight_1" name="route[flight]" required="required" value="1"> Dubai 00:30 26 Oct 2016 Dublin 09:10 26 Oct 2016
                Duration: 11h 40m  Stops: 2  Price: 402.27 EUR</label></div></div></div>
                </div>
                                 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="radio">
          <label class="required">
            <input type="radio" id="route_flight_0" name="route[flight]" required="required" value="0">Dubai 00:30 26 Oct 2016 Dublin 14:55 26 Oct 2016 Duration: 17h 25m Stops: 3 Price: 393.5 EUR</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `get the most previous element` that means first element inside DOM has `id^=` ? if i understand you `$("input[id^='route_segments_']").first();`

Comment: I expressed it wrong, I meant the closest previous element to the event firing radio button.

Comment: You're going to have problems with this HTML structure, because there's no clear relationship in the DOM between the `<input type="radio">` and the element you're trying to target.

Specifically, jQuery's `.prevAll` only looks at the previous _siblings_ of the element you start from: in this case, the `<label class="required">` that is the parent of your radio button. That label has no siblings, so `prevAll` returns nothing.

Comment: which input are targeting?what out put do you expect

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to target `route_segments_1_destCountry` here?

Will you possibly have more than one radio button? And how will the HTML look when you have more than one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018337/find-closest-previous-element-jquery here you can find the answer.

Comment: yes I have more radio buttons, but the problem is the radio button is deeper in the DOM then my targeted element.So maybe that's the reason why prevall is not working?

Comment: @PrimeSedrakyan - that's a very specific solution, I don't think it applies here (even though the title is similar).

Comment: each element must has unique id so the most previous parent element has id^= is the first id of DOM

Comment: I've answered, but I'm still not sure that this is what you want - could you make a JSFiddle with a simplified version of your HTML (don't worry about JS or CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have problems with this HTML structure, because there's no clear relationship in the DOM between the `<input type="radio">` and the element you're trying to target.

Specifically, jQuery's `.prevAll` only looks at the previous *siblings* of the element you start from: in this case, the `<label class="required">` that is the parent of your radio button. That label has no siblings, so `prevAll` returns nothing.

There are a few ways to define the relationship between the radio and the possible targets. One way is to wrap both the radio button and the targets in a known container, then look inside the container for the last match:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="routes">
  <li class="route">
     <input type="text" class="route-segment" value="route1"/>
  </li>
  <li class="route">
     <input type="text" class="route-segment" value="route2"/>
  </li>
  <li class="route">
     <input type="text" class="route-segment" value="route3"/>
  </li>
    <li class="route">
     <input type="text" class="route-segment" value="route4"/>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="transfers">
  <li class="transfer">
    <input type="radio" name="transfer-select" value="transfer-1">
  </li>
  <li class="transfer">
    <input type="radio" name="transfer-select" value="transfer-2">
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    // Cache the elements that we're going to need:
  var routes = $('.routes .route'),
      transfers = $('.transfers .transfer');

    // Whenever the selected transfer is changed, find the last route:
  transfers.on('change', 'input:radio', function(){
    var route = routes.last();
    //Find the input inside the last route:
    console.log(route.find('input.route-segment').val());
    //Find the input inside the second-to-last route:
    console.log(route.prev().find('input.route-segment').val());
  });
});
```

Comment: I created a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mvue4k43/#&togetherjs=plfgMt2O9N

I want to get the forms of "part two"